# validating JTextField after TAB

Tags: java, swing

I'm using the following code to validate the text in JTextFields Text1 and Text2.

```
private void Text1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    Text1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent EVT) {
                if(EVT.getKeyCode() == EVT.VK_TAB){
                     String value = Text1.getText();
                     int l = value.length();
                     if (EVT.getKeyChar() >= '0' && EVT.getKeyChar() <= '9') {
                          Text1.setEditable(true);     
                     } else {
                          Text1.setEditable(true);
                          Text2.setEditable(false);
                          label.setText("* Enter only numeric digits(0-9)");
                     }
                 }
          }
});
```

When I try entering a new correct value after a wrong value in Text1, Text2 still is un-editable. Am I missing something?

Comment: You always call Text1.addKeyListener when called Text1KeyPressed event handler ?

Comment: @SergeyGazaryan- I'm sorry but I don't get you.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: keyListeners are the _wrong_ tool in 90% of contexts anyway. In input validating contexts like here, the percentage climbs to 100% (because you are missing input by other means, f.i. paste). Instead, use a  formattedTextField (as @mKorbel suggested) or a documentFilter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

better would be to implements [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with Number Formatter, allow input decimal separator, negative sign and numbers in the range 0-9,

for listening changes in [TextComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) is there [DocumentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012222/how-to-strikethrough-text-in-a-jtextfield/8013129#8013129)

Answer (score 3):

You never make `Text2` editable again. Somewhere you should have the line:

```
Text2.setEditable(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because when you input a Wrong value and then validate it , you disable the Text2 field and then you don't enable it again in your code ...

I don't know what you want to achieve from your question but maybe it's enough adding set editable for Text2 here :

```
               if (EVT.getKeyChar() >= '0' && EVT.getKeyChar() <= '9') {
                            Text1.setEditable(true);
                            Text2.setEditable(true);
                    }
```