# JTextField listener when text changes that modifies textField's text

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtextfield, documentlistener

Any idea how I can add a text listener on to a JTextField, that triggers when the text changes and as an action modifies the JTextField's text.

I have tried using `addInputMethodListener` which seems to be appropriate but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried `textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener()` but this throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification` when I try to modify textField's text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DocumentListeners` do not permit the modification of the underlying document of the `JTextComponent`. You are looking for a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html).

[Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/CustomDocumentFilter.htm)

Comment: +1 [DocumentListeners](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8013129/714968), [DocumentFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9430683/714968)

Comment: @Reimeus It doesn't work; it throws `StackOverFlowError` because when I change textField's text it calls `replace` from `DocumentFilter` which calls `setText` and thus in infinite recursion.

Comment: @mKorbel I have said why it doesn't work with DocumentListener (and with DocumentFilter subsequently).

Comment: Don't call `setText` in the `DocumentFilter`, use the `replace` method from the  super class.

Comment: post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), could eb based on my posts in my comment here, everything is hidden in your code, your problem, nobody knows about that:-)

Comment: @Reimeus immediatelly go to the lottery and to buy a few Lotto tickets,