# How to strike through text in JTextArea in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am trying to add text in a JTextArea.
But i need some of the text to be strike through and some to added as it is.
I have searched over the internet, but couldn't find any answer.
Any help on what to refer?

Comment: `JTextArea` is meant for plain text, although you could change the font, I doubt it would give you the effect you're after. Consider using a `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane` instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to strikethrough text in a JTextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012222/how-to-strikethrough-text-in-a-jtextfield)

Answer (score 4):

`JTextArea` allow you set font style, but you cannot set style to text partially. Please see the code below, you can use `setFont` method to specify font with strikethru style, but it applies to all text in the `JTextArea`:

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
Font font = new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
Map fontAttr = font.getAttributes();
fontAttr.put (TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON);
Font myFont = new Font(fontAttr);
area.setFont (myFont);
area.setText ("Hello");
```

Whereas, if you want some text are in strikethru and some not, then you have to use `JTextPane` with `StyledDocument`, but I do not recommend this because you need a lot of tweaking to display your content with specific style. Below code may give you the idea:

```
DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
Style style = sc.addStyle("strikethru", null);
StyleConstants.setStrikeThrough (style,true);
doc.insertString (0, "Hello ", null);
doc.insertString (6, "strike through ", style);
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code. Here some of the strike text "@11@","@22@" and some to added text  "@yicHFRx1nc@" ,"@icHFRx1nc@" which replace of strike text.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class JTextAreaExample {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;

    public JTextAreaExample() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextAreaExample swingControlDemo = new JTextAreaExample();
        swingControlDemo.showTextAreaDemo();
    }

    private void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("JTextArea Example");
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);

        statusLabel.setSize(350, 100);

        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
        mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
        mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showTextAreaDemo() {
        headerLabel.setText("JTextArea");

        JLabel descriptionLabel = new JLabel("Description: ", JLabel.RIGHT);

        final JTextArea descriptionTextArea = new JTextArea("Enter String ", 5, 20);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(descriptionTextArea);

        JButton showButton = new JButton("Show");

        showButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String b = descriptionTextArea.getText().replace("@11@", "@yicHFRx1nc@")
                        .replace("@22@", "@icHFRx1nc@");
                System.out.println("b=" + b);
                statusLabel.setText(b);
            }
        });

        controlPanel.add(descriptionLabel);
        controlPanel.add(scrollPane);
        controlPanel.add(showButton);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Rafiq - how your answer is relevant? Question is about set some text in strike thru and some text normal. Not for replacing string in textarea.